# Using Java, take in a Json message, find a subset of fields, check said fields, then map to new Code values and export as Json

Tags: java, json, coding-style, mapping

Okay, I'm new to using Json in Java and heres what I'm looking to do.

Using Java I'm taking in a Json message, something like:

```
{ 
    "toy": [
        {
             "color":"red",
             "age":"2-4",
             "type": {
                 "format":"electronic",
                 "batteries":"Y"
             },
             "price":"$50"
        }
     ]
}
```

Now, say I have several of these coming through with different values for the fields above. I want to take the message and extract fields based on some requirements which will require certain fields to map to new fields. For example:

Requirement1

Field: color

Maps to: Colour

Field: batteries

Maps to: Batteries Required?

So the output would be:

```
{ 
    "Toy": [
        {
            "Colour":"red",
            "Batteries Required?":"Y"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then assume there may be other requirements requiring different fields or a combination of fields, or transformation of fields (like currency conversion).

I want to know what the cleanest and most efficient way would be. Does this kind of thing already exist in Json within Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use Jolt to transform Json objects like XSLT does for XMLs: https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt. Using this lib you can define a "transformation rule" that reads your input and produces a json based on the rules.

An alternative is Json Path, that allows you to find elements in a json object like in xpath: https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

Answer (score 1):

You can try little [jmom](https://github.com/antonsjava/jmom) java library

```
JsonValue json = JsonParser.parse(stringvariablewithjsoninside);
Jmom littlemom = Jmom.instance()
    .copy("/color", "/Colour", true)
    .copy("/type/batteries", "/Batteries Required?", true)
    .remove("/type", "/age", "/price")
    ;
Jmom mom = Jmom.instance()
    .copy("/toy", "/Toy", true)
    .apply(littlemom, "/Toy/*")
    ;
mom.apply(json);
String str = json.toPrettyString("  ");
```